# Bulk SMS service provider Business

Tags: sms, bulk, sms-gateway, gateway

I am planning to start a bulk sms service provider business. However I have the following doubts:

1. Which SMS/MMS Gateway software is good/best for high volume traffic(
   OzekiNG, NowSMS etc)?
2. Do I need to setup connections with all the
   major mobile operators or a single major operator will also work?
3. For the case of 2-way SMSs how can I charge money from the
   customers?(e.g. usually the operator charges for the sms, but I need
   to get something also)
4. How much will be the initial costing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider kannel? http://www.kannel.org/
2. It depend, to guarantee realiability, you should consider connect to the mobile operator. But it would seem a lot of mno in the world hence there are some other aggregators which you can connect to such as the one you mentioned in your first question.
3. You need something called reverse charging. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_SMS_billing for more information.
4. The cost will always depend on which operator you integrate with. So remember to quote for their initial costing. You can reference the operators pricing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can read following guide especially written for service providers mentioning that how one can [start VoIP based Voice SMS or FAX broadcasting business](https://www.ictbroadcast.com/how-become-internet-telephony-service-provider-itsp-using-ictbroadcast-sp-edition), Following are answers to your questions respectively

1. For bulk SMS traffic you must go with SMPP protocol, Fortunately kannel has good support for SMPP and its available freely.
2. Multiple providers are better, for Failover and comparatively lower cost due to LCR.
3. It is obvious that you will charge your clients for outgoing SMS. however for inbound you can earn from DID numbers ( user have to pay rent for their inbound number ) further if you have large number of active DIDs / Phone numbers you can earn money from providers too ( who send traffic to your DIDs ) against termination and SS7 dips. but its very advance topic and only feasible for big players.
4. For initial cost calculation you have to consider multiple things like Infrastructure and server setup, Software licensing fees and 3rd party cost regarding DIDs and Termination services.

Hope it will help